# how to use group by in the following linq query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I m a beginner in the LINQ syntax and need to write a linq query. Themes and Dataset_Meta tables are joined by **ID** and **Theme** columns in respective tables and I need a count of each theme used in Dataset_Meta table.

The following SQL gives me exactly what I require in linq

```
Select T.ThemeName , COUNT(DM.ID) 'Theme Count' from dbo.Themes T inner join dbo.Dataset_Meta DM on T.ID=DM.Theme group by T.ThemeName
```

I have started the following but unable to complete it

```
from Theme in DataContext.Themes
join Dataset_Meta in DataContext.Dataset_Meta on Theme.ID equals Dataset_Meta.Theme
select new
{

}
```

Comment: What did you find in the documentation for group by?  How did you try to use it and what problems did you have in your attempts to solve the problem?

Comment: @Servy its easier and quicker to look in the documentation and fix, or searching around then to type a question on SO and explain the issue in detail. As I m struggling to find appropriate example or walkthrough hence posted the question. Also I did post the bit I understood from the documentation

Comment: If it's easier to just look up the documentation then why didn't you do that at all?  You showed now attempt at grouping or counting the items, nor is there any reference to any documentation on the subject in your question.  There are many thousands of easily accessible examples of this behavior that are readily available for you, you only need to have bothered to look first.

Comment: Pls provide one link out of thousands of easily accessible examples  relevant to what i m looking and I will be thankful

Comment: ASK Google.  That's exactly what it's there for.  SO is not an "get someone to Google that for me" site.

Comment: Pls try to understand google is the first thing we try many times before posting and explaining the question

Answer (score -1):

Found this solution. Hope it helps someone.

```
from theme in DataContext.Themes
join Dataset_Meta Meta in DataContext.Dataset_Meta
on theme.ID equals Meta.Theme
group theme by new {theme.ThemeName,theme.ID} into grp
select new
{
 Name = grp.Key,
 Count = grp.Count()
};
```

Comment: Kindly provide a better solution if you've one